# laravel store input value into session without submit form

Tags: javascript, laravel

now doing project using laravel. if it possible to store the input value directly into session without submit button and the input value still exist evendo i refresh the page? how if the input name is array like this

```
<input class="outputcost" name="outputcost[10][0]">
<input class="outputcost" name="outputcost[10][1]">
<input class="outputcost" name="outputcost[10][2]">
<input class="outputcost" name="outputcost[23][0]">
<input class="outputcost" name="outputcost[23][1]">
<input class="outputcost" name="outputcost[50][0]">
```

im haven't so much knowledge for javascript. maybe there are have article or example code for this case. can share with me. please help me for this.

Comment: One thing you should know is that laravel is not asynchronous and will not store session without submission. To achieve this, you need a sort of ajax persistence request, which I won't recommend. Another alternative is to use javascript sessionStorage or localstorage.

Comment: ajax submit in the background